# Include within a while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sure my inability to solve this problem steams from a lack of knowledge of some aspect of php but I've been trying to solve it for a month now with no luck. Here is a simplified version of the problem.

In my database I have a members table, a childrens table (the children of each member), and a friend requests table (this contains the friend requests children send to each other).

What I'm attempting to do is display the children of a particular parent using the following while loop....

```
$query = "SELECT * From children " . <br>
         "WHERE parent_member_id = $member_id";     <br>  
$result = mysql_query($query) <br>
      or die(mysql_error());<br>
$num_children = mysql_num_rows($result);<br>
echo $num_children;<br>
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){<br>
   $first_name = $row['first_name'];<br>
   $child_id = $row['child_id'];<br>

<div>echo $first_name<br>

}
```

This while loop works perfectly and displays something like this...

**1) Kenneth

2) Larry**

What I'm attempting to do though is also display the number of friend requests each child has next to their name...like this

**Kenneth (2)

Larry (5)**

To do this I attempted the following modification to my original while loop...

```
$query = "SELECT * From children " .<br>
         "WHERE parent_member_id = $member_id";<br>



$result = mysql_query($query) <br>
      or die(mysql_error());<br>
$num_movies = mysql_num_rows($result);<br>
echo $num_movies;<br>
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){<br>

   $first_name = $row['first_name'];<br>
   $child_id = $row['child_id'];<br>

echo $first_name; include('counting_friend_requests.php') ;

}
```

In this version the included script looks like this...

```
$query = "SELECT <br>children.age,children.child_id,children.functioning_level,children.gender,children.parent_member_id,children.photo, children.first_name,friend_requests.request_id " .
         "FROM children, friend_requests " .
         "WHERE children.child_id = friend_requests.friend_two " .
         "AND friend_requests.friend_one = $child_id"; <br>

$result = mysql_query($query)<br>
  or die(mysql_error());<br>
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);<br>
if ($count==0)<br>
  {<br>
  $color = "";<br>
  }<br>
else<br>
  {<br>
  $color = "red";<br>
  }<br>
echo span style='color:$color' ;<br>
echo $count;<br>
echo /span;<br>
```

Again this while loop begins to work but the included file causes the loop to stop after the first record is returned and produces the following output...

**Kenneth (2)**

So my question is, is there a way to display my desired results without interrupting
 the while loop? I'd appreciate it if anyone could even point me in the right direction!!

Comment: Don't do sub queries like that; perform the join operation in MySQL itself.

Comment: ok...My concern with that was how to display the results of the friend requests table as only a number. Another words I'm worried I would get the following results...                              Kenneth (2) Kenneth (2) Larry (5) Larry (5) Larry (5) Larry (5) Larry (5)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained, are [officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp) and can be [dangerous in live code](http://bit.ly/4zUdtT). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2):

Avoid performing sub queries in code like the plague, because it will drag your database engine down as the number of records increase; think `<members> + 1` queries.

You can create the query like so to directly get the result you need (untested):

```
SELECT child_id, first_name, COUNT(friend_two) AS nr_of_requests
From children
LEFT JOIN friend_requests ON friend_one = child_id OR friend_two = child_id
WHERE parent_member_id = $member_id
GROUP BY child_id, first_name;
```

It joins the `children` table records with `friend_requests` based on either friend column; it then groups based on the `child_id` to make the `count()` work.

Comment: Thanks so much! I definitely need to learn more about creating effective queries...I'm guessing I would then just echo $nr_of_requests within the loop in-order to display the number of friend requests for each child record?

Comment: @matttuman Right, the number of requests would be stored in `$row['nr_of_requests']`; btw, consider switching over to PDO / mysqli while you're at it :)

Comment: Haha...yeah I kinda picked up on the fact that I should make that switch...thanks again!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again...your query works great but I also need to add a where clause to it...this is what I have... 'SELECT child_id, first_name, COUNT(friend_two) AS nr_of_requests
From children Where parent_member_id = $member_id
LEFT JOIN friend_requests ON friend_one = child_id OR friend_two = child_id
GROUP BY child_id, first_name;'                                                         The addition of this where clause causes the script to produce an error message...again any help you can give would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @matttuman Forgot about that; added to my answer, the `WHERE` goes after the join but before the group by.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include the php file everytime you loop.  Try creating a Person class that has a method getFriendRequestCount().  This method can all the database.  This also means you can create methods like getGriendRequests() which could return an array of the friend requests, names etc.  Then you could use count($myPerson->getFriendRequests()) to get the number.  Thousands of options!

A great place to start, http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Another example of a simple class, http://edrackham.com/php/php-class-tutorial/

Eg.

```
include ('class.Person.php');  
while(loop through members)
    $p = new Person(member_id)
    echo $p->getName()
    echo $p->getFriendRequestCount()
    foreach($p->getFriendRequests as $fr)
         echo $fr['Name']
```

In your Person class you want to have a constructor that grabs the member from the database and saves it into a private variable.  That variable can then be accessed by your functions to proform SQL queries on that member.

Comment: Judging from that code, the performance will be just as bad because sub queries are performed in code rather than database.

Comment: The least of his problems is performance.   Yes you can just do a join, or even a nested SELECT that counts the number of rows returned.  I was suggesting a more OO approach to his problem that can be extended in the future.

Comment: In fact performance was never mentioned anywhere in his question.

Comment: To successfully abstract a database into an object model takes considerably more time than fixing one query, so although one should strive to make code more maintainable, it should be secondary to actually fixing the problem. Besides, knowing how naively applied OOP easily contributes to very inefficient queries, it's better to first learn how queries should be written.

Comment: OP's problem wasn't SQL, it was including a file in a while loop.  Plus who's to say $p->getFriendRequestCount() doesn't return $this->person->num_of_friend_requests from a JOIN'd SQL statement anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify whats happening here.

"include" processing is done when the script is parsed. Essentially its just copying the text from the include file into the current file. After this is done the logic is then parsed.

You should keep any include statements separate from you main logic. In most cases the "include"d code will contain definitions for one or more functions. You can then call these functions from the main body of your program at the appropriate place.